# Unable to implement angular flex layout stretch property

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-flex-layout

I am new to angular flex layout and working on angular 2 applications using flex layout.

I am trying to build a simple login page as shown below.

[image]

### Below shown is my **myform.component.html**

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary" ><span class="span">SPACE STUDY</span></mat-toolbar>

<div class="card-container">

<mat-card  class="card-content">    

            <form  (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(user.username,user.password)" #myForm="ngForm" class="form-elements">
                             <br/>
                             <mat-icon style="-webkit-text-fill-color:#6A5ACD">account_circle</mat-icon><br/>
                             <p>LOGIN</p>

                                <mat-input-container class="form-row">
                                    <span matTooltip="Username">
                                        <input matInput placeholder=" " id="username" [(ngModel)]="user.username" name="username">
                                    </span>
                                    <span matPrefix><mat-icon style="color: black;"></mat-icon></span>
                                </mat-input-container>

                                <mat-input-container class="form-row">
                                    <span matTooltip="Password">
                                        <input matInput placeholder=" " id="password" [(ngModel)]="user.password" name="gpassword" [type]="hide ? 'password' : 'text'">
                                    </span>
                                    <span matPrefix><mat-icon style="color: black;"></mat-icon></span>
                                </mat-input-container>

                                <div class="checkbox">
                                <mat-checkbox>REMEMBER ME</mat-checkbox>
                                </div><br/>
                    <button mat-raised-button color="primary" type="submit" mat-raised-button style="border-radius:15px;max-height:6vh;">Login</button>

                    <mat-progress-bar mode="indeterminate" *ngIf="showprogressbar"></mat-progress-bar>
            </form>

</mat-card>

</div>
```

### Below shown is my **myform.component.css**

```
.mat-toolbar{
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 35vh;
}
.span{
   font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:16px;
}
.card-container {
  background-color: white;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.card-content {
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  min-width:70vh;
   align-content: stretch;
   align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
.form-elements{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.mat-icon {
    transform: scale(4);
}
.form-row{
   align-content: stretch;
}
.checkbox{
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:12px;
}
```

### Below is my actual output window

[image]

As you can see above i want to take half of my form card over the mat-toolbar component.

I tried using padding and margin but its not giving me proper alignment.Can anybody please help me to align my form card as same in the first picture.

Also i tried applying stretch property to the mat-input-container to stretch the form input lines,but its not working..

please help me how to apply flex CSS to achieve my requirement..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you don't know, but Angular already has a flex layout system.

It's called **Flex Layout**, and **[you can find it here](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout)**. it allows you to get rid of that repetitive CSS code for flexing your views.

Basic usage in your project :

```
<mat-card  class="card-content" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="center center">
  <form ... fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="center stretch">
    ...
  </form>
</mat-card>
```

About your issue, I believe the `stretch` value can be applied to the `align-items`, not the `align-content` property.